# smart pointer in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, smart-pointers

Story is: I have to make a class for my programming class and my custom project (Space Marine - yeah, I'm a bit of a fan) is in progress. But I found a problem I just can't simply solve. Here are some codes that I think are important:

HEADER

```
class SpaceMarine
{

public:
...
    SpaceMarine(); // default constructor
    SpaceMarine(std::string name, 
                unsigned int rang, 
                Statystyki& stats, 
                std::auto_ptr<Pancerz> armor, Bron& weapon);

private:

    std::string name_;
    unsigned int ranga_;
    Statystyki* stats_;
    std::auto_ptr<Pancerz> armor_;
    Bron* weapon_;
    Experience experience_;
```

just to make it clear : "Statystyki", "Pancerz" and "Bron" are classes that are members of main class SpaceMarine. Project requirements: I have to make one smart pointer (here as auto_ptr).

.CPP

```
SpaceMarine::SpaceMarine()
{
    name_ = "John";
    stats_ = new Statystyki();
    weapon_ = new Bron(); 
    std::auto_ptr<Pancerz> armor_(new Pancerz());


   ranga_ = 0;
}
SpaceMarine::SpaceMarine(std::string name, 
                         unsigned int rang, 
                         Statystyki& stats, 
                         std::auto_ptr<Pancerz> armor, Bron& weapon) 
: armor_(std::move(armor))
{
    name_ = name;
    ranga_ = rang;
    stats_ = stats;
    armor_ = std::move(armor);
    weapon_ = weapon;
}
```

Now, where the problem begins:
This is the part of "main.cpp" file:

```
SpaceMarine SM1;
SpaceMarine SM2("Azrael", 3, S2, **P2** , B2);
```

// S - Stats, P - armor, B-weapon class

There is problem with this little thingy, called P2, which should be an auto_ptr to armor. I have armor object P2 declared previously. 
I have problem "merging" auto_ptr into my constructor. Any ideas?

Also, all advices about improving my code are welcome :)

Matt

Ps. My first post here! :D Go easy on me ^^

**EDIT**

Thanks to user1158692 for tidying my code
Thanks to Hansmaad and user1158692
I wish I could make both your answers right for this probleme, as both helped me to deal with it ;)

Here's the final code for future refrence:

HEADER

```
SpaceMarine(std::string name, 
            unsigned int rang, 
            Statystyki& stats, 
            Pancerz& armor, 
            Bron& weapon);
```

.CPP

```
SpaceMarine(std::string name, 
            unsigned int rang, 
            Statystyki& stats, 
            Pancerz& armor, 
            Bron& weapon);

{
    name_ = name;
    ranga_ = rang;
    stats_ = &stats;
    std::unique_ptr<Pancerz> armor_(&armor);
    weapon_ = &weapon;
}
```

// and example of declaring it in main.cpp

```
Bron B2("Chainsword" , 0, 6);

Pancerz P2("Power armor", 12);

Statystyki S2(6,6,4,8,20);

SpaceMarine SM2("Azrael", 3, S2, P2 , B2);
```

Comment: I *highly* recommend using a proper smart pointer (like `std::unique_ptr`) in C++11 (which you evidently use from the `move` call). Even before that, there's still Boost's. You're also not initializing or setting your smart pointer data member in the default constructor. It's a good idea to use constructor initializer lists. You're also assigning plain objects to pointers and currently have no need to take them by non-const reference.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11 because it has weird copy semantics, as suggested by chris you should really use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Well you move the contents of the `auto_ptr` argument into your member variable `auto_ptr` twice - once in the initialiser list and once in the constructor body.  The second time you do it, the source will be in a "null" state from the time before so will wipe out the destination member variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass a `auto_ptr` to your constructor. It will transfer ownership to the copy.
However, `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated and should be replaced by `std::unique_ptr`.

```
struct A {};
struct B 
{
    std::auto_ptr<A> a;
    B(std::auto_ptr<A> a) : a(a)
    {      
    }
};

struct C
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    C(std::unique_ptr<A> a) : a(std::move(a))
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<A> a{ new A };
    B b{ a };

    C c{ std::make_unique<A>() };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the armor object is to share the lifetime of the SpaceMarine (and the smart pointer suggests it is) then why is it on the heap at all, not the stack?

Still, if that's the way you're going then consider defining the class and constructor like this (some parameters and so on left out for brevity)::

Declaration:

```
class SpaceMarine
{
public:
    SpaceMarine(Pancerz* armor);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Pancerz> armor_;
};
```

Implementation:

```
SpaceMarine::SpaceMarine( Panzerc* armor )
: armor_(armor)
{
}
```

Called like:

```
SpaceMarine obj( new Panzerc() );
```

or

```
Panzerc* ptr = new Panzerc();
.   
.
SpaceMarine obj( ptr );
```